# Dynamic link in IF/ELSE statement

Tags: php, dynamic, hyperlink

I apologize for any misuse of terminology...I'm a noob...

I have a dynamically created page that contains a dynamic link. I added an IF/ELSE statement to display a different word based on the number of items in the variable $rowsphoto.

The different words display correctly, but the URL that is generated contains all of the PHP instead of generating the correct URL.

This is the original code, which works fine:

```
<?php if($portfolioid != 0) { ?>
    <div class="extrafield">Additional works in <a href="index.php?option=com_jartists&view=portfolio&aid=<?php echo $artistid;?>&pid=<?php echo $portfolioid; ?>&album=<?php echo $albumid;?>&id=<?php echo $photoidd; ?>&Itemid=105" class="portfoliocol">Portfolio:</a></div>
```

This is the code I have after adding the IF/ELSE statement:

```
<?php if($portfolioid != 0) { ?>
    <div class="extrafield">    
<?php
if ($rowsphoto <= 4){
    echo "Additional works in <a href='index.php?option=com_jartists&view=portfolio&aid=<?php echo $artistid;?>&pid=<?php echo $portfolioid; ?>&album=<?php echo $albumid;?>&id=<?php echo $photoidd; ?>&Itemid=105' class='portfoliocol'>Edition:</a>";
} else {
    echo "Additional works in <a href='index.php?option=com_jartists&view=portfolio&aid=<?php echo $artistid;?>&pid=<?php echo $portfolioid; ?>&album=<?php echo $albumid;?>&id=<?php echo $photoidd; ?>&Itemid=105' class='portfoliocol'>Portfolio:</a>";
}                          
?>
</div>
```

I ran the code through a couple syntax checks and they all came back with no errors. What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Comment: Technically this is valid syntax, but it isn't what you want. You don't want `<?php echo $var; ?>` in the middle of a string. You are already in php because you are echo'ing out the string. What you are doing is just echo'ing out that literal string with the variable. What you likely want to do is just wrap your variables in curly braces so your string ends up like `echo "test{$foo}bar";`

Comment: You can't use PHP tags inside PHP, you just need to escape the string bounds and use the `.` concatenation operator instead of trying to open new PHP tags, e.g. `echo "String here" . $varname;` as opposed to `echo "String here<?php echo $varname; ?>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off using it correctly like this:

```
<?php if($portfolioid != 0): ?>
    <div class="extrafield">
    <?php if($rowsphoto <= 4): ?>
        Additional works in <a href='index.php?option=com_jartists&view=portfolio&aid=<?php echo $artistid; ?>&pid=<?php echo $portfolioid; ?>&album=<?php echo $albumid; ?>&id=<?php echo $photoidd; ?>&Itemid=105' class='portfoliocol'>Edition:</a>
    <?php else: ?>
        Additional works in <a href='index.php?option=com_jartists&view=portfolio&aid=<?php echo $artistid; ?>&pid=<?php echo $portfolioid; ?>&album=<?php echo $albumid; ?>&id=<?php echo $photoidd; ?>&Itemid=105' class='portfoliocol'>Portfolio:</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You're mixing `html` and `php` very badly. You should be separating them to keep your code clean and concise.

---

Your issue with it displaying the php instead of the correct variables is because ([as @scrowler said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954760/dynamic-link-in-if-else-statement/27954860#comment44304638_27954760)):

> You can't use PHP tags inside PHP, you just need to escape the string
>   bounds and use the . concatenation operator instead of trying to open
>   new PHP tags, e.g. echo "String here" . $varname; as opposed to echo
>   "String here"

Comment: thanks – worked like a charm! and makes complete sense to me now.

Comment: Pleasure mate, glad I could help! Also @Aaron, [this](http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) will help you understand the shorthand syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

While Darren's answer is correct, alternatively you can just stay inside of php

```
<?php
    if($portfolioid != 0) {
        echo '<div class="extrafield">';    

        if ($rowsphoto <= 4){
            echo "Additional works in <a href='index.php?option=com_jartists&view=portfolio&aid=$artistid&pid=$portfolioid&album=$albumid&id=$photoidd&Itemid=105' class='portfoliocol'>Edition:</a>";
        } else {
            echo "Additional works in <a href='index.php?option=com_jartists&view=portfolio&aid=$artistid&pid=$portfolioid&album=$albumid&id=$photoidd&Itemid=105' class='portfoliocol'>Portfolio:</a>";
        }                          

        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```